# Generate Call Graph Model in MoDisco

Tags: android

I read this file [1
Testing Android Apps
T
hrough Symbolic Execution]:
http://mason.gmu.edu/~nesfaha2/Publications/JPF2012.pdf

They wrote:

> We parse the app’s source code using MoDisco [19] and extract the app’s call graph model

I installed MoDisco but not sure what to do.

So my question is how can I to create this Call Graph Model?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhBeR.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having installed MoDisco, you can select Discovery -> Actions -> Display Method Calls from the package explorer context menu. This opens the view. However it looks a bit different than the image you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Modisco's discoverer plugin to generate a XMI file and then import it into a graph database such as [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/) or 
 [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/). It's not that difficult, just parse the XMI and use the codeRelation and ActionRelation sections as edges of your graph model.